# How can I throw away local git commits when getting "Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged"?

Tags: git

I have the following message in git:

```
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 3 and 8 different commits each, respectively.
#   (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
```

I would like to throw away the 3 local commits, and pull the 8 remote commits at origin/master.

(Merging is going to be too difficult, I'd rather make the 3 local commits again once master is up to date.)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 368, accepted):

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Note that any non-pushed commits or local changes will be lost.

Comment: can you do `git reset origin/master` without `--hard` so that working directory changes are not lost?

Comment: I see a similar message but for non-master branch when I rebase it to latest master. What would a pull do in that case? Should I pull? I want my commit to be on the latest changes.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan: Pull will (attempt to) merge in your existing changes.  Reset will throw them away.

Comment: these 2 commands worked straight away. Only extra thing is, I need to restore back the changes I did previously from backup I took. Cheers!

Answer (score 43):

To preserve your old commits on a temporary branch in case you need them:

```
git branch temp
```

Then switch to the new master

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: So in this case does he branch his branch ? If for example he was working in 'mydevbranch' then does branch temp this simply creates a new copy branch of mydevbranch ? It seems like a precautionary measure the way you put it incase they are ever needed they are in this copy..

Comment: Yes, this is a precautionary measure. It just ensures that the commits are not lost should you need them in the future.

Comment: intuitively I would have thought that you would need to comit your local code before doing this - and thats the problem because you dont want what you just did to go upstream. I guess you comit local and dont push - but eventually it would need to go up...thats unwanted I am assuming.

A branch is for a variation or different feature but it needs to happen from a comitted state ? Or maybe thats what you are saying. Perhaps I need to NOT worry about comitting - I just thought branch takes a copy from the comitted source origin (loosing local changes)

Comment: @landed: yes, you'd commit your local changes after making branch `temp`. You can later, if you want to recover some of those commits, cherry-pick them (see `git help cherry-pick`).

Comment: Thanks, after git reset hard, then `merge temp` solved my problem

Answer (score 10):

Try doing this to blow away your local commits:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~4
```

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to merging, you can rebase the feature branch onto master branch using the following commands:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

Answer (score 4):

If a hard reset doesn't cut it for you and you don't want to do a pull-merge you can throw away your local unwanted changes by deleting your local branch and re-download the origin one:

```
git branch -D <local branch>
git checkout -b <branch name> origin/<branch name>
```

Using `main` as an example:

```
git branch -D main
git checkout -b main origin/main
```

Comment: If the local branch is diverged from 'origin/<branch>', it doesn't allow to delete the local branch.

Answer (score 4):

To erase your latest local commit use the following:

```
git reset HEAD^
```

This will get the header back to the state previous to the commit, and will allow you to `git pull` from master. Make sure you save all your changes elsewhere (locally) before pulling from the remote repository.

To be able to pull without conflicts use `git stash`, and then `git pull`.